# Reset WPF ComboBox to IsSelected value in Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell

Not too sure what I am missing here, but I have a few comboBoxes in a form and I would like to hit a "Clear" button and reset all the values to the original SelectedItem value.

xml:

```
<Window

  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="213" Width="513">

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbox_Values" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="247,77,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Value1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Value2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Value3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button x:Name="btn_Clear" Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,77,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" Height="21" FontSize="11"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

If I do it this way:

```
$wpf_btn_Clear.Add_Click({
    $wpf_cbox_Values.SelectedItem.Content = "Value1"
})
```

The current value gets wiped:
[image]

If I do it this way:

```
$wpf_btn_Clear.Add_Click({
    $wpf_cbox_Values.SelectedItem.Content = "Value1"
    $wpf_cbox_Values.Items.Add("Value2")
    $wpf_cbox_Values.Items.Add("Value3")
})
```

I get doubles:

[image]

I am looking for the button to "reset" the comboBox with the original IsSelected item from the xml. For example, if i select Value3, then click the "Clear" button, the value goes back to Value1. This is in Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$wpf_cbox_Values.SelectedIndex = 0` and/or `$wpf_cbox_Values.SelectedItem = $wpf_cbox_Values.Items[0]` should work.

Comment: this did it ^^^ ```$wpf_cbox_Values.SelectedItem = $wpf_cbox_Values.Items[0]```

Answer (score 0):

[ComboBox.SelectedIndex Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1)

Perhaps try...

```
$wpf_btn_Clear.Add_Click({
     $wpf_cbox_Values.SelectedIndex = 0
})
```

Should keep your values, but set combobox index to zero which would be your first entry ("Value1").

Comment: This method gave me duplicates like the second example in my question.